# Is anyone reviewing close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Is anyone reviewing close votes? I hardly ever see other people in the list of recent reviewers. Or does the queue not show questions to everyone with the ability (i.e., does it assign a question to five people and only they are prompted in the queue to review it, and if they don't log in then others aren't chosen?)

Comment: Speaking for myself, I prefer to give the asker the benefit of the doubt, and wait for em to re-word and clarify. I close only when I believe that even after attempts at salvaging it, the question does not belong here.